# innerHTML of clicked element

Tags: javascript, dom

How could I get the innerHTML of a clicked element on a page of a random website, using a favelet or a script injector? 
By example, clicking right above the "Ask Question" of this page would return something starting with: `<div class="nav mainnavs " style="">
                    <ul style="">
                            <li style="">`.

I tried editing a favelet from slayeroffice.com whose initial purpose was removing children of the selected element, but it doesn't seems to work.

```
javascript:
var b = new Array();
var c= 1;
var d;
document.onkeydown = ck;
el = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++)
    {
        if (el[i].tagName.search(/(HTML|BODY)/i) == -1) 
        {
            if (el[i].title) el[i].oldTitle = el[i].title;
            el[i].title = el[i].innerHTML;
            d=String(el[i].innerHTML);
            el[i].onclick = function(e)
            {
                t = this;
                if (window.event) e = window.event;
                if ((t == e.target) || (window.event)) alert(d);
                if (window.opera) e.stopPropagation();
                return false;
            };
            el[i].onmouseover = function() 
            {
                if (!c) return;
                c = 0;
                t = this;
                b[t] = t.style.backgroundColor;
                t.style.background = '#DADADA';
            };
            void(
            el[i].onmouseout = function()
            {
                t = this;
                t.style.backgroundColor = b[t];
                c = 1;
            });
        }

    }
function ck(e) 
{
    k = window.event ? window.event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
    if (k == 27) 
    {
        for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
            if (el[i].tagName.search(/(HTML|BODY)/i) == -1) 
            {
                el[i].oldTitle ? el[i].title = el[i].oldTitle : el[i].removeAttribute('title');
                el[i].onclick = null;
                el[i].onmouseover = null;
                el[i].onmouseout = null;
                el[i].style.backgroundColor = b[t];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can just attach an event to the document onclick handler. No need for looping through every element on the page. Clicks will bubble up to it...

```
document.onclick = function(event) {
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    alert ( target.innerHTML ); 
};
```

However I recommend using a better method for attaching the event handler than with '=' as it will override any previously defined events that may be crucial to page operation.

I have used this snippet before for better event attaching without jQuery...

```
var bindEvent = function(elem ,evt,cb) {
        //see if the addEventListener function exists on the element
        if ( elem.addEventListener ) {
            elem.addEventListener(evt,cb,false);
        //if addEventListener is not present, see if this is an IE browser
        } else if ( elem.attachEvent ) {
            //prefix the event type with "on"
            elem.attachEvent('on' + evt, function(){
                /* use call to simulate addEventListener
                 * This will make sure the callback gets the element for "this"
                 * and will ensure the function's first argument is the event object
                 */
                 cb.call(event.srcElement,event);
            });
        }
    }
```

You just call...

```
bindEvent(document,'click', function(event) {
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    alert ( target.innerHTML ); 
});
```

Comment: or you could have just done var `target = event.target || event.srcElement;`

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly and is also simpler; that's more than what I hoped for.

Comment: How to use this function to attach event to particular element? such as bindEvent("button",'click', function(event) {, that attach event only to buttons

Comment: @JaganK You need to get the element `document.getElementById('blah')` see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Answer (score 3):

You will have issues with the scope of `i` in a for loop.

`i` will be equal to `el.length` when the clicking happens.

But why use a variable, when you can read it

change

```
if ((t == e.target) || (window.event)) alert(d);
```

to

```
if ((t == e.target) || (window.event)) {  
    alert(this.innerHTML);
}
```

Also shouldn't you be checking for srcElement on window.event?

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I had in mind when I tried different code modifications. Sadly, it also show that the initial code doesn't really fit for this task.